# Calculate $\iint\limits_D {\sqrt {{x^2} - {y^2}} }\,dA$ ...

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$\iint\limits_D {\sqrt {{x^2} - {y^2}} }\,dA$$ where $D$ is
>   the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

I get the following integral $$I = 2\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^x {\sqrt {{x^2} - {y^2}} } \,dydx} $$ I would appreciate some hints or help in solving this integral.

The answer $\frac{\pi }{6}$ somehow implies that the solution may be obtained by introducing polar coordinates. I tried solving it with polar coordinates setting the integration limits $0 \ldots \frac{\pi }{4}$ for $\theta $ and $0 \ldots \tan \theta $ for $r$ and multiplying the result by 2. However, i could not get the right answer...

Comment: Polar coordinates may be overkill, try a trig substitution instead. Treat $x$ as a constant when integrating w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: If i set $y = x\sin t$ i would need to change the limits and dydx using Jacobian?

Comment: Yes, any change of variables will involve using the Jacobian. In this case, you have $dy\,dx=x\cos t\,dt\,dx$.

Comment: I'd also like to add that, should you choose to convert to polar coordinates, the line $x=1$ translates to $r=\sec\theta$, not $\tan\theta$.

Comment: Thanx! Solved it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon 0\leq x\leq 1\land -x\leq y\leq x\}$.

The integral then comes equal to  $\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1\int \limits _{-x}^x\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$.

You can get away with the one dimensional substitution $y=x\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the polar approach:
$$D=\left\{(r,\theta)\mid 0\le r\le\sec\theta,\,0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{4}\right\}$$
and so you have
$$2\iint_D dA=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r\,dr\,d\theta$$